# For a system of sets closed under union and complement, does there always exists a partition generating it

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $\mathcal E \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ be a non-empty system of sets over $X$ which is closed under arbitrary union and complement (and hence also by intersection and set difference).

Then is it always possible to find a partition of $X$ in $\mathcal E$, i.e. a family of sets $\{ P_i \}_{i\in I}$, $P_i \in \mathcal E$, whose union is $X$ and which are pairwise disjoint, such that every $A \in \mathcal E$ could be written as a union of sets from $\{ P_i \}$?

If $X \subseteq \mathbb N$, then I am able to prove this claim. But for arbitrary $X$ I am not able to proof it, but I am also unable to find a counter example. I conjecture it to be true even in the general setting, as the closure properties are very unrestrictive, but if it is true; how to prove it, or otherwise do you know a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true: let $\sim_\mathcal{E}$ be defined by $$x\sim_\mathcal{E}y\iff \forall A\in\mathcal{E}(x\in A\iff y\in A).$$ Then the $\sim_\mathcal{E}$-equivalence classes partition $X$, and induce $\mathcal{E}$, since $A\in\mathcal{E}=\bigcup_{x\in A} [x]_{\sim_\mathcal{E}}$. Moreover, since $$[x]_{\sim\mathcal{E}}=\bigcap_{x\in A\in\mathcal{E}}A,$$ and $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under arbitrary intersections, each $[x]_{\sim_\mathcal{E}}$ is in $\mathcal{E}$.

---

If, however, we demand only closure under *finite* unions/intersections, the answer is *no*: defining $\sim_\mathcal{E}$ as before, it's easy to show that $\mathcal{E}$ is generated by a partition iff it is generated by the partition in $\sim_\mathcal{E}$-classes. But let $X$ be any totally disconnected topological space in which no singleton is clopen (e.g. Cantor space), and let $\mathcal{E}$ be the collection of clopen sets in $X$. Then:

- $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under finite intersections and under complements
- $[x]_{\sim_\mathcal{E}}=\{x\}$, but
- no singleton is clopen.

Comment: Thank you, now I see it clearer. But $\mathcal E$ as given is closed under *arbitrary* unions (and intersections), and I guess we have $[x] := \bigcap_{x \in A, A \in \mathcal E} A \in \mathcal E$, so as I see it this is always possible?

Comment: @StefanH Whoops, I misread - so yes, the answer is yes, every $\mathcal{E}$ has this property. I've edited to fix it.